# Why does PineScript tells me that my TEMA is not a function?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to apply the Triple Moving Average to CCI, but I get the error "tema is not a function". Could someone help me? Thank you very much.
Here is my code :

```
    //@version=4

study("my Script",overlay=false)

//Input
Temalength = input(30, title="Tema Length")

src=close

EMA1= ema(src, Temalength)
EMA2 = ema(EMA1, Temalength)
EMA3 = ema(EMA2, Temalength)
tema = (3*EMA1)-(3*EMA2)+EMA3


//CCI
CCI = cci(src, 10)
emaCCI = tema(CCI, 20)

plot(emaCCI, title="TemaCCI", linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Because it is not a function. `tema = (3*EMA1)-(3*EMA2)+EMA3` defines it as a variable.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the solution @BarisYakut

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
tema (x, y) => 
    EMA1 = ema(x, y)
    EMA2 = ema(EMA1, y)
    EMA3 = ema(EMA2, y)
    (3*EMA1)-(3*EMA2)+EMA3
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it